# SSRS - DateValue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, datediff

in SSRS, i am trying to return a DateValue that is the first day of the next month after the selected month/year.  Everything works with my formula except when i try to evaluate on the month of December.  The formula works for all other months (evaluating on "4" yields an output of 1/1/(year selected +1) for example), but December returns a #Error every time.

My formula is:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Month.Value="12",(DateValue("1" & "/" & Parameters!Year.Value+1)),(DateValue(Parameters!Month.Value+1 & "/" & Parameters!Year.Value)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at using `DateAdd` and `DateSerial`.

So an expression like:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month
  , 1
  , DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value, Parameters!Month.Value, 1))
```

This uses `DateSerial` to construct the first of the month for the selected *Year* and *Month*, then uses `DateAdd` to add another month to this.

Worked fine on a basic report I made to test the expression:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize DateValue(), but don't you mean to include the day, as well as the month and the year?

```
=IIF(Parameters!Month.Value="12",(DateValue("1/1/" & Parameters!Year.Value+1)),(DateValue(Parameters!Month.Value+1 & "/1/" & Parameters!Year.Value)))
```

You could also use CDate(datestring) to convert a string into a date.  See [SSRS Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) and [Type Conversion Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I've tried using the CDate(datestring) too.  What happens is the IIF(Month="12",CDate(datestring),CDate(datestring)) works as long as i don't have the CDate(datestring) as the "then" in the IIF statement.  As soon as i add in the CDate(datestring) in as a Then to my condition, the formula #error with every month selection of 12.

Answer (score 0):

IIf and Switch always evaluate all paths, so for December this part of the formula

```
DateValue(Parameters!Month.Value+1 & "/" & Parameters!Year.Value)
```

fails, because Parameters!Month.Value+1 would be 13 and there is no 13th month.
To avoid this you have to change that part to something like this:

```
DateValue(IIf(Parameters!Month.Value<12,Parameters!Month.Value+1,12) & "/" & Parameters!Year.Value)
```

It will never be displayed for December but still be evaluated.